# Why is my vue3 component not updating when I use a method?

Tags: vue.js

I have a card picker component that let's the user pick a number of cards from a deck. This is my Vue3 code:

```js
<template>
  <v-layout row justify-center>
    <card3
      v-for="(card, index) in cards"
      :key="index"
      :card="card"
      :cardWidth="cardWidth"
      :isSelected="contains(card, selectedCards)"
      v-on="$listeners"
    ></card3>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, contains, watch, computed } from "@/common"
import Card3 from "@/components/Card3.vue"
import { Cards, Card } from "@/types"

type Props = {
  selectedCards: Cards
}

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    cards: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    selectedCards: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    faceUp: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    cardWidth: {
      type: Number,
      default: 16
    }
  },
  components: {
    Card3
  },

  setup(props: Props, context) {
    const { selectedCards } = props

    return {
      contains
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

The component takes cards and selectedCards from the parent component. It then makes a check to see if the card is selected before passing that information on to a child component which renders the card and puts a border around selected cards.

Everything is working as expected at this point!

However, now I want to make one small refactor. I make a method isSelected and expose it to the template:

```js
const isSelected = (card: Card) => contains(card, selectedCards)

return {
  contains,
  isSelected
}
```

I then use the method in the template instead of contains:

```
:isSelected="isSelected(card)"
```

However, the component has stopped working now! The selectedCards is updated as expected but the child component is not updating the selected cards as expected. The border indicating the selected cards is not being rerendered when I make this single change.

Can someone explain me why?

I have tried to put all this into a working example on codesandbox.io but I had to give up unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried changing `:isSelected="isSelected(card)"` to `:isSelected="(card: Card) => contains(card, selectedCards)"` ?

Comment: yes, I have...and that is not working either

Comment: Right. Can you add `Card3` component code as well?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem is that I am destructuring my props and thereby loose reactivity.

If I instead do this:

```
const isSelected = (card: Card) => contains(card, props.selectedCards)
```

or this:

```
const { selectedCards } = toRefs(props)
```

...then I (apparently) keep reactivity and it works. Talk about a gotcha!

Thanks for the help!